# "Sign in to GitHub" prompt to enable GitHub Copilot on every VS Code launch

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

very time I launch VS Code, I am asked to **Sign in to GitHub** to enable **GitHub Copilot** suggestions. regardless of doing that many times.

[image]

I'm a bit confused because I also have GitLens extension which works fine.

Anyone else faced something similar?

---

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 Focal Fosa

Comment: Maybe better asked at [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Note GitLens uses the local git repo, independent of which remote (if any) you're using, so the fact that that works doesn't really tell you anything about GitHub auth.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I find it quite annoying as well

Comment: @BelgoCanadian nope, I just found a workaround but not a solution. I will post an answer for more details...

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10 as of April 2, 2022.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (Archlinux) I hadn't installed a keyring storage thingo - similar to @Delta.

So install it:

```
pacman -S gnome-keyring
```

And make sure that it's launched when your log in:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --all
gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets
```

There appear to be lots of different causes/fixes mentioned in various places on the web, so if this doesn't fix it, keep browsing :)

Comment: arch user here, want to confirm this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution but figured out a workaround NOT SAFE. use it at your own risk!

Go to:

1. Passwords and keys
2. select Login under Passwords
3. double click on *vscodevscode.github-authentication/github.auth* and
4. hit the **delete passwor** button
5. you may also wanna delete *vscodevscode.microsoft-authentication/microsoft.login*

these two *secrets/passwords* are associated with vscode and prompts you on every launch if left default(not deleted)

Comment: What is this "Passwords and keys"? Is it in Windows? I'm having a similar issue on Linux.

Comment: @ErayErdin that's in Ubuntu, Linux. not sure about windows mate, switched from it some time ago...

Comment: I deleted everything vscode/microsoft related (3 items), and it worked!. Thanks!

Comment: on ubuntu there's seahorse gui app for managing keyrings

Answer (score 2):

It took me whole week to figure this out for Debian using DWM window manager.

If you use dwm or ion3 like me. You need to launch dbus and keyring-daemon.

```
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh) &
export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK &
source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh &
exec dbus-launch dwm
```

This might be done better. But now I have a problem that I have no keyrings on my system. Also as after I've created a keyring with password I couldn't unlock it, because user password didn't work. So here's a workaround:

- `rm -rf ~/.local/share/keyrings/*`
- launch `seahorse`
- On top-left (before "Passwords and Keys") hit `+` and choose "Password keyring", name it "Login" and ***DO_NOT*** set password.
- Launch vscode, push sign-in button "Default keyring" will be created
- Pop up will appear with asking to enter new password, do not enter anything, push create

You'll end up with an unlocked two keyrings, and then vscode github copilot login started to work.

Comment: This nearly worked for me. I created the login keyring but vscode wasn’t writing to it. Had to set it to default by hand. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-keyring.

`yay -S gnome-keyring` on arch.
`apt install gnome-keyring` on ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried that when I initially faced the problem but gave it another shot but that wasn't a success... 
I am not the only one facing this and there's a thread in Github. here's(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120392#issuecomment-1059743849) another person with my outcomes
thanks though @Delta